# Learning to find the Smallest Common Multiple Using ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6, higher-order-functions

The code I wrote times out at a higher range. Any way to optimize the code by just using higher-order ES6 functions.

The link to the online environment:
https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Return the Smallest Common Multiple for pair of Input Numbers.
  
  const [min, max] = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b); 
  // Sorting Input Array to give min and max values for the range

  const range = Array(max-min+1).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i+min);
  // Initialize the Array

  let prodAll = range.reduce((product,number)=>product*number);
  // Finding the product of all numbers which is a gauranteed multiple of the range


  let res = Array(prodAll/max).fill(0).map((_,i)=>(i+1)*max) // Initialize an Array of all the multiples of the 'max' number upto 'prodAll'
                            .find(mulp=>range.every((val)=>mulp%val===0)); // check if any number meets the divisiblable criteria sooner then 'prodAll'
        

  return res;
}

console.log(
  smallestCommons([1,13])
)
```

Comment: The [Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm) is an efficient method that you can use to find the GCD, which once found, you can find the LCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
function smallestCommons(arr) {
  // Return the Smallest Common Multiple for pair of Input Numbers.
  
  const [min, max] = arr.sort((a,b)=>a-b); 
  // Sorting Input Array to give min and max values for the range

  const range = Array(max-min+1).fill(0).map((_,i)=>i+min);
  // Initialize the Array

  let res = range.reduce((lcm, number) => {
    // Calculate the least common multiple using the current value and the previously calculated lcm
    return (lcm * number) / gcd(lcm, number);
  }, max);

  return res;
}

function gcd(a, b) {
  if (b === 0) {
    return a;
  }
  return gcd(b, a % b);
}

smallestCommons([1, 4]);
```

This version uses the `reduce` function to iterate through the range and calculate the least common multiple using the current value and the previously calculated lcm.  It also uses separated function (`gcd`) to calculate the greatest common divisor using Euclid's algorithm, which is more efficient.